# How do I round corners in every ListView item..?

Tags: android, listview

So, I have faced with one problem. I have a ListView looking like this :

[image]

Well I have been looking a long time to find answer to my problem. So my problem is that I cannot round corners in every item I am able to just round corners to all listview. This is my listview style code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/green">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/red"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/listviewstyle">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone help me to find out how to round every listview item corner?

Answer (score 2):

You should apply a `style` to every element of your list, rather than applying it to the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

set

```
android:background="@drawable/listviewstyle"
```

to every item of the list

Answer (score 1):

You are currently applying your style to your entire list, you really need to set it just on the adapter, and not on the entire list.

In your example, you need to remove this line from your ListView XML:

```
android:background="@drawable/listviewstyle"
```

Then in the adapter you are using your list element, put this there.  (Hint: this is the layout you use to describe "Element 1, and "Sub-element 1", which is not included here).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `shape-drawable` and give the `radius` whatever  value you need

**custom_list_item.xml** (in `drawable` folder). I use these properties for a custom `Toast` but you can change to your needs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
 <solid android:color="@drawable/white"/>
    <corners
      android:bottomRightRadius="45dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="45dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="45dp"
      android:topRightRadius="45dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="@drawable/orange"
        android:width="3px"/>
</shape>
```

Then you create a `layout` for your `ListView` items. You can make this `shape-drawable` the background for the list items or put it in a style in `styles.xml` and apply the style to your `ListView` items `layout`

In **styles.xml** create the style

```
<style name="CustomListItem" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_list_item</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/black</item>
</style>
```

Then in your custom list item `layout` add

```
style="@style/CustomListItem"
```

Comment: @pskink Yeah because it's not applied to each item

Comment: no, he wants his ListView to be "clipped" by a round rectangle, thats why you see last visible item round but not becouse its round by itself but rather the round list view clips it

Comment: @pskink I may be wrong but I don't think so. That is the current result but the OP said, "how to round every listview item corner?". So it sounds to me like the OP wants **every** corner of **every** item to be rounded.

Comment: Ok,  you may be right but there is old ancient saying "one picture is worth more than 1024 words"

Comment: @pskink and that is a very good saying. That is why I used the picture **and** the words to see that the OP is getting that result. So, if that's what was wanted there wouldn't be a question. But the picture is not the desired result ;)

Comment: didn't answer his question, he wants the rounded corner for each item